# How do different programming languages treat relative paths?

Tags: unix, relative-path

I'll start with an example from PHP. Say I have a file structure like this:

```
.
└── includes
    ├── file.php
    └── test.php
```

And say that my code looks like this:

```
// includes/test.php
require 'file.php';


// includes/file.php
echo 'SUBDIR';
```

Now, if I run `php includes/test.php`, I get `SUBDIR` as output. This is unsurprising.

But say I add a file at `./file.php` that says `echo 'ROOT!';`. Now my tree looks like:

```
.
├── file.php
└── includes
    ├── file.php
    └── test.php
```

And when I run `php includes/test`, it outputs `ROOT!`.  I find this a bit astonishing.

When I think about it, what I find astonishing about it is not necessarily that `file.php` refers to something in the current working directory, but that before when it *didn't* find `file.php` in the current working directory, it looked in `includes`, relative to the file doing the `require`. It seems there is a subtle hierarchy to how PHP treats relative paths.

Note that if in `includes/test.php` I have `require './file.php';` instead (a leading `./` where before there was just a "bare" file path), it works as expected **IFF** the "upper" `file.php` exists. That is, with a leading `./` it doesn't load `includes/file.php` and Fatal Errors.

Practically, all this boils down to: **Don't use relative paths! Use absolute paths instead!** That's not what I'm asking about.

What I'm wondering is, **Is this just a UNIX thing? Is it enforced at the OS level, or simply by convention in programming languages? Do other languages behave differently?**

Thanks.

Comment: What's your `include_path`?

Answer (score 0):

It's never (or at least, very rarely) an operating system thing; most (maybe all) operating systems have a fixed an immutable method of resolving relative pathnames. It's almost always either a language thing or an implementation thing; that is, the behavior is documented either in the language standard or in the implementation manual.

For example, the behavior of PHP `include` and `require` is [documented in the official PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the `include_path` specified. If the file isn't found in the `include_path`, `include` [and `require`] will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing.
>
> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or `\` on Windows, or `/` on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with `.` or `..`) — the `include_path` will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with `../`, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

Other languages do it differently, of course. For example, in C and C++, `#include` directives are handled by the preprocessing step; the standards of those language explicitly say that  the search for the file to be included is implementation-defined; the actual search rules are defined and documented by the specific compiler.